# Flask and Python how to make search engine for data from mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to make some kind of search engine for student's information by entering their first name in html input field, but I have some troubles with my code. I am using Flask with Python though. 
Here is my project.py code:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="", db="cs324", host="127.0.0.1")
        c=db.cursor()
        c.executemany('''select * from student where name = %s''', request.form['search'])
        for r in c.fetchall():
            print r[0],r[1],r[2]
            return redirect(url_for('search'))
    return render_template('search.html')
```

Here is my search.html code:

```
{% extends "hello.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="search">
<form action="" method=post>
    <input type=text name=search value="{{ request.form.search}}"></br>
    <div class="actions"><input type=submit value="Search"></div>
</form>
</div>
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class=flash>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I hit Search button nothing happens, I checked database it has some data in it so it is not empty, I can't find where am I making a mistake, please help?

Comment: Did you check your browser's error console? What happens if you type `<your_hostname>/search` in the address bar?

Comment: Yes, I even tried putting app.run(debug=True) but it doesn't show anything it looks like it just refreshes the search.html page.

Comment: @SrdjanRistic When you click the button, do you see in your web app access log any entry? What url it declares? Then, if it hits the url you are expecting.

Comment: It shows: http://localhost:5000/search and that's it. When I remove redirect to search page it still does the same...

Comment: I suggest you not using connection related staff in the views instead make a separate method for db connection and keep it during the application life cycle, and you can make use of flask-sqlalchemy for database related matters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Make sure, action point to proper url

I think you render the form with wrong `action` for submitting the form.

Your version is using `action=""` and I guess, it shall be `action="/search"`

So your template shall be changed like:

```
{% extends "hello.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="search">
<form action="/search" method=post>
    <input type=text name=search value="{{ request.form.search}}"></br>
    <div class="actions"><input type=submit value="Search"></div>
</form>
</div>
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class=flash>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

## Do not redirect out of your result

Your existing code is processing POST, but within first loop it ends up returning with `redirect`

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="", db="cs324", host="127.0.0.1")
        c=db.cursor()
        c.executemany('''select * from student where name = %s''', request.form['search'])
        for r in c.fetchall():
            print r[0],r[1],r[2]
            return redirect(url_for('search')) # <- Here you jump away from whatever result you create
    return render_template('search.html')
```

## Do render your template for final report

Your code does not show in POST branch any attempt to render what you have found in the database.

Instead of `print r[0], r[1]...` you shall call `render_template()`

Something like this

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="", db="cs324", host="127.0.0.1")
        c=db.cursor()
        c.executemany('''select * from student where name = %s''', request.form['search'])
        return render_template("results.html", records=c.fetchall())
    return render_template('search.html')
```

Comment: @SrdjanRistic I extended my answer, there were two other problems - you redirected out from whatever you have created in very first `for` iteration. And you forgot to render resulting page on your return of POST.

Comment: Why does `request.form()` take 'search' and not '/search'?

Comment: @Pyderman because there are two concepts, one being path on url (the `"/search"`) and the other are default values to fill into form (and this is `request.form.search`). These concepts have different meaning and shall not be mixed.